# Check if List<object> contains all integers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, I want to check if all items in this list are integers or not and return true if all values are integers. How can I do that?

List can have all strings or all integers or combination of both. I want to return true only if it contains all integers.

Comment: Look at every item in the list and see if it's a number?

Comment: do you want it to return true if the string is an Integer as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var isAllInts = lst.All(x => x is int);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Igor Mentioned You can do this

```
var isAllInts = lst.All(x => x is int);
```

But just incase you want to see if the string is an int aswell you can

```
int testVal = 0;
var isAllInts = lst.All(x => int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out testVal));
```

Comment: Or in C# 7.0, `var isAllInts = lst.All(x => int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out var _))`. (Though cheating a bit since wildcards didn't make it.)